# Why is this Entity's property missing a SET statement

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reviewing some sample code where a User property is defined and (as far as I can tell) is functioning correctly:

```
**        [Required]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return mFirstName; }
            set { mFirstName = value; }
        }

        [Required]
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return mLastName; }
            set { mLastName = value; }
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
        }
**
```

There's validate class running against this Entity but doesn't include FullName:

```
protected override void ValidateUpdate(User entity)
{
    applySimpleRules
    (
        entity,
        x => x.FirstName,
        x => x.LastName,
        x => x.Phone1,
        x => x.Email,
        x => x.Address,
        x => x.City,
        x => x.State,
        x => x.Zip,
        x => x.Password
    );
```

As I say, the project is saving and editing everything I test except one specific record that looks, structurally like all the rest - has a legal First and Last but this function (called by the above function) is choking and seems to be flagging 'Full Name' which, again... _shouldn't be in the list of validated fields.

But I'm not clear why the code fails to include a setter and wonder if that's coming into play.

thx

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding the question. Your code doesnt produce a setter for fullname because their isnt one. And where abouts is it choking and what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why it's failing, but it doesn't have a setter because the property isn't persisted.  I'm assuming EntityFramework here, in which case, it needs to have a public getter/setter to be persisted.  Perhaps you could include the code for `applySimpleRules`?